# bad creditionals spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement simple auth using jdbc and spring security. When I input correct login and password, it returns "Bad creditionals" error.

SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({"controller", "dao", "config"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth
            .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 'true' as enabled from user where username = ?");
}
```

index.jsp (login form is here)

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>This is secured!</h1>
  <p>
    Hello <b><c:out value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"/></b>
  </p>
  <c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/>
  <form class="form-inline" action="${logoutUrl}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suppose my mistake is somewhere in jsp. Thanks in advance.

part of logs:

```
00:21:53,683  INFO Dialect:122 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
00:21:53,758  INFO TransactionFactoryInitiator:68 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
00:21:53,759  INFO ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:48 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
00:21:53,760 TRACE TypeFactory:72 - Scoping types to session factory org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@6411d3c8
00:21:53,766  INFO SchemaUpdate:182 - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
00:21:53,766  INFO SchemaUpdate:193 - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
00:21:53,886  INFO SchemaUpdate:205 - HHH000396: Updating schema
00:21:53,889  INFO TableMetadata:65 - HHH000261: Table found: TESTDB.PUBLIC.DISK
00:21:53,890  INFO TableMetadata:66 - HHH000037: Columns: [user_id, id, title]
00:21:53,890  INFO TableMetadata:68 - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk2081bd40df9925]
00:21:53,890  INFO TableMetadata:69 - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_2, fk2081bd40df9925_index_2]
00:21:53,892  INFO TableMetadata:65 - HHH000261: Table found: TESTDB.PUBLIC.TAKENITEM
00:21:53,892  INFO TableMetadata:66 - HHH000037: Columns: [user_id, id, disk_id]
00:21:53,892  INFO TableMetadata:68 - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fkd18bb05aad3f6fe5, fkd18bb05a40df9925]
00:21:53,893  INFO TableMetadata:69 - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_4, fkd18bb05aad3f6fe5_index_4, fkd18bb05a40df9925_index_4]
00:21:53,895  INFO TableMetadata:65 - HHH000261: Table found: TESTDB.PUBLIC.USER
00:21:53,895  INFO TableMetadata:66 - HHH000037: Columns: [password, id, email, enabled, username]
00:21:53,895  INFO TableMetadata:68 - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
00:21:53,895  INFO TableMetadata:69 - HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_273]
00:21:53,896  INFO SchemaUpdate:240 - HHH000232: Schema update complete
00:21:54,016  INFO SimpleUrlHandlerMapping:315 - Mapped URL path [/WEB-INF/pages/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
00:21:54,027  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181 - Mapped "{[/index],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView controller.MainController.index()
00:21:54,027  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181 - Mapped "{[/disks],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView controller.MainController.getDisks()
00:21:54,027  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181 - Mapped "{[/],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String controller.MainController.hello()
00:21:54,028  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181 - Mapped "{[/u/disks/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView controller.MainController.getUserDisks(int)
00:21:54,028  INFO RequestMappingHandlerMapping:181 - Mapped "{[/index22],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView controller.MainController.index22()
00:21:54,030  INFO HibernateTransactionManager:341 - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource@610df783] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
00:21:54,042  INFO DefaultSecurityFilterChain:28 - Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5c82cd4f, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@46d9aec8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3bead518, 
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@1cc9cfb2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1c504e66, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2257fadf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@17740dae, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7144655b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@14379273, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7918c7f8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@35835e65, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@14bf57b2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@cfbc8e8, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3c6aa04a]
    00:21:54,061  INFO DispatcherServlet:480 - FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher': initialization completed in 523 ms
```

Comment: Are you encrypting the passwords?  Is there any debug output?

Comment: No encryption, no debug messages

Comment: Not sure if you are suing spring boot or not, but if so, check this out: add this line to your `applicaition.properties` file: `logging.level.org.springframework.security:TRACE`.

Comment: If not using spring boot, then you want to enable trace logging in your `log4j.properties` or `slf4j.properties` for `org.springframework.security`

Comment: Added logs and changed SecurityConfig (added query), nothing interesting in logs though.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out. It needs additional table with authtorities.

Comment: You should post the answer here so that someone else who has the question can get this solved (and so you get free up-votes which translated to reputation)